# Angular 5 router-outlet not working in Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, angular

So i've built the default angular cli app. Created:

```
newroute.component.ts & newroute.component.html
```

app.component:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Created a new route component:

```
import {NewrouteComponent} from './newroute/newroute.component';
import {ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/newRoute', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'newRoute',
    component: NewrouteComponent,
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Injected that into the module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NewrouteComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    routing,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    CordovaService,
    DeviceService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Cordova build:

```
cordova emulate android
```

which calls:

```
ng build --target=production --environment=prod --output-path cordova/www/  --base-href .
```

Android 6+ works fine and shows the content of the  shows, however in Android 5.1.1 the  content does not display and in the console i see:

> ERROR TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   main.ecb766387713c84cc90f.bundle.js:1 TypeError: undefined is not a
>   function

It seems that at the most basic level Android does not support routing in 5.1.1?

Any ideas?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ng5",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-ide": "^0.9.39",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I' don't know if work, but try use HashLocationStrategy  https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy

Comment: Same error happens unfortunately.

Comment: Check version of Cordova. I make a app Angular 5 and using Android 5.0.2 works

Comment: I'm on cordova 8, which are you using?

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2017, Cordova 6.3.1 node.js 4.4.3 npm 2.15.0, cordova android 5.21 (yes, I know it's not the better -is a old project-)

Comment: Still the same with cordova 5.4.1, android 5.1.1. Surely npm and node wouldn't make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, Dezza, I'm sure no a expert cordova. try to do a simple example to know if the problem is in the code and not in Cordova :(

Comment: Could you share you package.json or compare it to my edit?

Comment: sure, check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the app not working correctly is that 5.1 Android version uses an old version of Chrome (as to what we're used to now). Therefore, when doing any ES6 or modern Javascript such as array.apply() the app would fall over.

To fix this simply un-comment the polyfills in polyfills.ts. Don't be naive thinking that this documentation applies to only IE, Chrome requires it as well:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this help you, but I write how I make the app

I make the app using angular-cli. after build ng build --prod, change the index.html remove the "base tag", and change the script tag: is < script>...< /script> NOT only < script ../>

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My App</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="styles.e85e86d6d65752737800.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
     <!--check that the script tag is <script>...</script> NOT <script ../> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.1aea26911fb58219f5a8.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.ad37cd45a71cb38eee76.bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.d1e85e225566be5f9e29.bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Create in Visual Studio 2017 a black cordoba and put the dist folder that ng build --prod create and the "index.html" in the www folder

My index.js (in www/scripts) to make back-button works is like

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    var 

    function onDeviceReady() {
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown.bind(this), false);
        StatusBar.hide();


        var parentElement = document.getElementById('deviceready');
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    };

    function onConfirm(buttonIndex) {
        if (buttonIndex === 1)
            navigator.app.exitApp();

    };
    function onPause() {
    };

    function onResume() {
    };

    function onBackKeyDown(e) {
        navigator.notification.confirm("Do you really quit the app?", onConfirm, "My app", ["OK", "Cancel"]);

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

    };

} )();
```

The only pluggins I've installed was:

- Notification 1.3.4
- StatusBar 2.3.0
- Whitelist 1.2.2

In my app, the package.json is simple

```
{
  "name": "my-app-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.37",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

And the angular-cli.json it's not diffenrent to anothers

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-app-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "app/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

And in my app.component I used HashLocationStrategy

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ....
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true },
   .....
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Others things. I've not used jquery nor bootstrap.js (just bootstrap.css)
I hope this help you, but as you can see it's not especial

Comment: Thanks man, i can't get it to work still after matching your code. IT's very odd as the content displays but not the content of the <router-outlet>